# Set property on ViewModel from View

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

What do I need to add to set a public property on my ViewModel instance from my View? I'd like to set some properties on the ViewModel resource rather than bind it from some element in my view.

**View XAML:**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="mainViewModel" MyProperty="30" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.DataContext>
   <Binding Source={StaticResource mainViewModel}" />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

**MainViewModel.cs (implements INotifyPropertyChanged)**

```
private int _myProperty;
public int MyProperty{
    get { return _myProperty; }
    set 
    { 
        _myProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }
}
```

The setter on MyProperty is never called. There must be some fundamental MVVM thing i'm doing wrong.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVVM.  You are doing something else wrong.  This actually will work, I've done it several times.

Comment: Ok thanks. I got it to work. My problem was that the viewmodels' constructor is called before the value is set, and my code wasn't expecting this.

Comment: I suggest you add your last command as an answer, and mark it as accepted. ;)  This will make the solution much more visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My psuedo code above actually works. I had another issue with my ViewModel's constructor which had me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would create a binding which binds the property on the ViewModel with a property of a control. For example you could bind MyProperty to a textbox like so:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty}" />
```

Since the parent data context specified by UserControl.DataContext is an instance of MainViewModel, this binding will bind to a property of that object.

Comment: I don't want the user to be able to change MyProperty, nor should it be visible on the page. I'm using the same ViewModel across multiple views with each having a different value for MyProperty.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Well what you can do is set the MouseDown of a control such as a 'save' button on a method of the code-behind of your view. Then in the codebehind, you set your ViewModel's property or call his method.
```

In your View.xaml.cs you need something like this

```
    private MyViewModele myVM;

    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Initialized);  //After loading, call Initialized(...)
    }

    private void Initialized(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myVM= this.DataContext as MyViewModele ; //Reference to your ViewModel
    }

    private void Label_General(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       myVM.Property = "w/e"; //Set the ViewModel property
    }
```

In your View.xaml

```
<Label 
        Content="Click this label"
        MouseDown="Label_General"
        >
</Label>
```

Here i setted the Property to a static string but you can retrive any of your View's control and use its value to push it in your ViewModel.

I hope this answer your question.